# Rails: Authentication with slack workspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slack

Currently I am trying to add Slack integration into an application. The users on the app should post on the app at the same time post to their own slack workspace automatically.

Gem `omniauth_slack` makes it access to the workspace I myself own, but this is not working for authenticating with other workspace.

[The authentication for workspace](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth) requires these info below:
* client_id
* scope
* redirect_uri
* state
* team

Update `omniauth.rb` like this.

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :slack,
      'CLIENT_ID',
      scope: 'team:read,users:read,identify,bot',
      token: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
end
```

Other codes are here.

**apps/controllers/slack_controller.rb**

```
class SlackController < ApplicationController
  def callback
    p request.env['omniauth.auth'].info
    redirect_to '/'
  end    
end
```

**apps/views/home/index.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to 'Slack authentication', '/auth/slack' %>
```

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'omniauth-slack'
```

**config/routes.eb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root 'home#index'
  get 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'slack#callback'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to put something like this

```
 Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
   provider :slack,
   ENV['CLIENT_ID'],
   ENV['CLIENT_SECRET'],
   scope:'chat:write,commands,im:write,users:read'
  end
```

and if you are going to use the Api methods you need to configure slack with the token

```
class SlackMessages

  def Initialize

   Slack.configure do |config|
    config.token = "xoxp-xxxxxx234234324..."
   end

    @client = ::Slack::Web::Client.new

  end

  def postmessage
    @client.chat_postMessage(options)
  end

end
```

create an initializer named slack and put something like this:

```
Slack::Events.configure do |config|
  config.signing_secret = ENV['SIGNING_SECRET']
end
```